# Ajax multiple object return - Parsing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am unable to parse the multiple object JSON on ajax success. But I can, when I receive a single object JSON.

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/filter.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        category: $categoryArr,
        brand: $brandArr,
        occasion: $occasionArr,
        colour: $colourArr,
        price_min: $price_min,
        price_max: $price_max
    },
    success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#result").html(data["name"]);
    }
});
```

PHP code for single object JSON

```
$products = R::findOne('products', $filterString, $filterArray); //returns single row from db
if (!empty($products)) {
    echo $products;
} else {
    echo "No Products are available for this search criteria";
}
```

Result:  {"id":"1","name":"Malbari-Product1","brand_id":"1","category_id":"1","colour_id":"2","occasion_id":"2","price":"599","discount":"10","small_img":"images/products_small/1.png","big_img":"images/products_big/1.jpg","seller_id":"1"}

PHP code for multiple object JSON

```
$products = R::find('products', $filterString, $filterArray); //returns multiple rows from db
if (!empty($products)) {
    echo $products;
} else {
    echo "No Products are available for this search criteria";
}
```

Result:  {"id":"1","name":"Malbari-Product1","brand_id":"1","category_id":"1","colour_id":"2","occasion_id":"2","price":"599","discount":"10","small_img":"images/products_small/1.png","big_img":"images/products_big/1.jpg","seller_id":"1"}  {"id":"10","name":"Malbari-Product6","brand_id":"2","category_id":"1","colour_id":"1","occasion_id":"5","price":"350","discount":null,"small_img":"images/products_small/6.png","big_img":"images/products_big/6.jpg","seller_id":"2"}

I suppose, in case of multiple objects, i'm actually getting a single string instead of multiple object JSON.

Please help.

Comment: `JSON.parse` is *not* needed here.  `dataType: "JSON",` should tell jQuery to do that for you.

Comment: Can you paste some example return data sets, so we have an idea of what we are looking at?

Comment: You need to run a loop in the response when it returns multiple objects

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Exactly, but the trick seems to be working only in case of single object. It is treating multiple object JSON as a string!

Comment: I don't know what your `$products` variable contains, but at least your error messages are not valid json. I would recommend you collect all information and only at the end do a `echo json_encode($all_info);`

Comment: $products contains result set from db query

Comment: Yes, but in what format, an array, a json string, an object, etc. And don't suppose what you are actually getting, just do a `var_dump` or a `console.log` of the result.

Comment: I have posted the result. In case of single return, I get an object and for multiple values, I get a set of objects as string.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you just want to return an array of JSON objects?

```
[ { "Name":  "Object1" }, { "DifferentObject": "Object2" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it seems that the problem is with the php `find()` and `findOne()` methods.

In order to use them both in the same way, it would be convenient to make sure both methods return a similar result like an array with either one or more objects in it. That way you can use them both the same way in your javascript.

What I would do, is create an empty array and add the results as objects in that array. You can return that array from your methods and where you now `echo` your results or error message out, you simply do an `echo json_encode($function_result_or_error_message);`. I would probably add an error key and message to the array before I do that to have the error message contained in the result.

For more details you would have to post your php `find()` and `findOne()` methods.